# select the first of two or more filenames and save only the first

Tags: python

I want to save files with these filenames:

```
filenames = [
    '4_66\nNUC_66377\nAPPR\nWONDER',
    '4_66\nNUC_66377\nAPPR\nCOT',
    '8_21\nAKRO\nNUT\nAMY'
    ]
```

and if the filename starts with the same number before underscore, then write to file only the first filename.

So, I am doing:

```
for idx in range(len(filenames)-1):
    if filenames[idx][0:2] != filenames[idx + 1][0:2]:
        with open('./' + filenames[idx] + '.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write('111')

# save the last file
with open('./' + filenames[-1] + '.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('111')
```

But if you run the code, it saves the second one!
`'4_66\nNUC_66377\nAPPR\nCOT'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rely on `set` containment check to only process the files with encountered unique custom prefix:

```
fn_set = set()
for f in filenames:
    pfx = f[:f.find('_')]  # prefix before underscore
    if pfx not in fn_set:
        f.write('yourdata')
        fn_set.add(pfx)
```

Comment: Ok, nice! So, in order to write the files: `fn_set = set()
for idx, f in enumerate(filenames):
    pfx = f[:f.find('_')]  # prefix before underscore
    if pfx not in fn_set:
        with open('./' + filenames[idx] + '.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write('yourdata')
            fn_set.add(pfx)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `==` instead of `!=`.

> *But if you run the code, it saves the second one!*  `'4_66\nNUC_66377\nAPPR\nCOT'`

It happens at the second iteration. You're comparing pairs of prefixes and if there is no match (like in the 2nd iteration, `4_` is different from `8_`) you're saving to the first file of the pair not the group :

```
# 1st iteration; idx=0
'4_66\nNUC_66377\nAPPR\nWONDER'  '4_66\nNUC_66377\nAPPR\nCOT'

# 2nd iteration; idx=1
'4_66\nNUC_66377\nAPPR\nCOT'     '8_21\nAKRO\nNUT\nAMY'
```

Comment: **NB**: Changing `!=` to `==` won't work if there is more than two files sharing the same prefix.